# How to get service tags based on service route?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm working on a permission system and I'd like to get information about all the admin classes loaded in Sonata.
I have a list of all these classes via

```
$this->getConfigurationPool()->getAdminClassas();
```

I would like to get the defined tags (Group / Label) for these services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Groups / Labels by calling `getDashboardGroups()` on `getConfigurationPool()`

```
$groups=$this->getConfigurationPool()->getDashboardGroups();
$adminGroups=array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($groups as $key => $val) {
    $adminGroups['groups'][$i]['label']=$val['label'];
    foreach ($val['items'] as $items) {
        $adminGroups['groups'][$i]['items'][]=$items->getLabel();

    }
$i++;
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($adminGroups);echo '</pre>';
```

So the resultant `$adminGroups` array will have all groups and its admin titles in below form

```
Array
(
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Group 1
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Menu item 1
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Group 2
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Menu item 1
                            [1] => Menu item 2
                            [2] => Menu item 3
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Group 3
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Menu item 1
                            [1] => Menu item 2
                        )

                )
   /*And so on ....*/
        )
)
```

Above will return admin labels which are set to show_in_dashboard = true to all admin labels you can get them by their service ids

```
$services = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getAdminServiceIds();
$container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
$adminLabels = array();
foreach ($services as $key => $val) {
    $admin = $container->get($val);
    $adminLabels['label'][] = $admin->getLabel();
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($adminLabels);echo '</pre>';
```